# I have been asked to see if conditional formating cvan assist us in this spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I need to have different cells react to conditional formatting depending on a certain date.
Example  Current accreditation valid to April 2 2017, so I need that cell to be Tan fill.
If the accreditation is over 12mths old from today date then the cell turns Red
Also if accreditation is due within the next month the cell to turn green

How do I do this and is it possible without to much unnecessary work.
I know I can conditional format to change a cell to meet one need but cannot manage multiple conditions Sorry to be a pain  I am using excel 2016 Chas

Comment: Shouldn't a cell with accreditation due April 2 2017 be green because it's due within the next month from today?

Comment: Yes my bad. I have several cell requirements. If I could attach a file or image it would show what I need

Comment: Mark Fitzgerald, What I need is 3 conditions to be met Tan Training coming up in the next month, Red Training overdue Green Fully compliant. All revolve around Todays date being whatever date today is. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not the most intuitive system, but it can be done.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-conditional-formatting-rule-precedence-063cde21-516e-45ca-83f5-8e8126076249

Comment: Thanks I may have most of it worked out, just some side issues within the spreadsheet I was given. It seems all dates in sheet are not actually in date format so that has created an issue which I can and am correcting now. Appreciate all the assistance